# Zikr ( wazaif ) afer 5 Salat

Tags: salat, dhikr

Can anyone please let me know the Zikr and amal after 5 Salah from **Sahih Hadith**. I would be happy if you kindly break it down by prayer times, like Fajr, Zuhr, Asar, Magrib and Isha.

Comment: Dhikr (zikr) is clear but what do you mean whit amal? Do you mean sunna/nafl prayers? If so their are some before a fard/farz and some after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Praise to Allah Subhan O Taala and blessings on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His family and Companions

There are many supplications and zikr during the day and night but as you have only asked for special Zikr and wazaif after Salah from "Sahih Ahadith ",,so I have compiled some of them which Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him did himself and some he taught to his companions too ,

Summarizing them I would present first concisely and then below are references.

---**After Salah:**

**‏ "لاَ إِلَهَ إِلاَّ اللَّهُ، وَحْدَهُ لاَ شَرِيكَ لَهُ، لَهُ الْمُلْكُ، وَلَهُ الْحَمْدُ، وَهْوَ** **عَلَى كُلِّ شَىْءٍ قَدِيرٌ،
اللَّهُمَّ لاَ مَانِعَ لِمَا أَعْطَيْتَ، وَلاَ مُعْطِيَ لِمَا مَنَعْتَ، وَلاَ يَنْفَعُ ذَا الْجَدِّ** **مِنْكَ الْجَدُّ ‏"‏‏.‏**

---**After Every Salah** :

**سبحان الله، والحمد لله، والله أكبر**

(33 Times).

---**After Fajr Prayer**:

‏ **اللَّهُمَّ إِنِّي أَسْأَلُكَ عِلْمًا نَافِعًا وَرِزْقًا طَيِّبًا وَعَمَلاً مُتَقَبَّلاً** ‏"‏ ‏"

---**After Salah** :

**استغفر الله**

(3 times).

:‏ **‏"‏اللهم أنت السلام، ومنك السلام، تباركت يا ياذا الجلال والإكرام‏**"‏

( 1 Time).

---**After Every Salah**:

**‏ اللهم أعني على ذكرك، وشكرك، وحسن عبادتك‏"‏‏**.‏"

(1 Time).

---**After Witr Prayer** :

**سُبْحَانَ الْمَلِكِ الْقُدُّوسِ**

( 3 Times and raise your voice on the 3rd time).

---**After Every Salah**:

**لا إله إلا الله وحده لا شريك له ، له الملك وله الحمد ، وهو على كل شيء قدير ‏.‏ لا حول ولا قوة إلا بالله ،لا إله إلا الله، ولا نعبد إلا إياه، له النعمة، وله الفضل وله الثناء** **الحسن‏.‏ لا إله إلا الله مخلصين له الدين ولو كره الكافرون**

---**After Every Fardh Salah:**

**اللّهُ لاَ إِلَـهَ إِلاَّ هُوَ الْحَيُّ الْقَيُّومُ
لاَ تَأْخُذُهُ سِنَةٌ وَلاَ نَوْمٌ
لَّهُ مَا فِي السَّمَوَاتِ وَمَا فِي الأَرْضِ
مَن ذَا الَّذِي يَشْفَعُ عِنْدَهُ إِلاَّ بِإِذْنِهِ
يَعْلَمُ مَا بَيْنَ أَيْدِيهِمْ وَمَا خَلْفَهُمْ
وَلاَ يُحِيطُونَ بِشَيْءٍ مِّنْ عِلْمِهِ إِلاَّ بِمَا شَاء
وَسِعَ كُرْسِيُّهُ السَّمَوَاتِ وَالأَرْضَ
وَلاَ يَؤُودُهُ حِفْظُهُمَا**
**وَهُوَ الْعَلِيُّ الْعَظِيمُ**

(Ayat Al Kursi 1 time).

*Now Below are the references from Sahih ahadith.*

> أَنَّ رَسُولَ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم كَانَ يَقُولُ فِي دُبُرِ
> كُلِّ صَلاَةٍ إِذَا سَلَّمَ ‏ "‏ ل**اَ إِلَهَ إِلاَّ اللَّهُ،
> وَحْدَهُ** **لاَ شَرِيكَ لَهُ، لَهُ الْمُلْكُ، وَلَهُ الْحَمْدُ،
> وَهْوَ عَلَى كُلِّ شَىْءٍ قَدِيرٌ، اللَّهُمَّ لاَ مَانِعَ لِمَا**
> **أَعْطَيْتَ، وَلاَ مُعْطِيَ لِمَا مَنَعْتَ، وَلاَ يَنْفَعُ ذَا الْجَدِّ مِنْكَ الْجَدُّ** ‏"
>
> Narrated Warrad: (the freed slave of Al-Mughira bin Shu`ba) Al-Mughira
> wrote to Muawiya bin Abu Sufyan that Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) used to say
> at the end of every prayer after the Taslim, "La ilaha illa-l-lahu
> wahdahu la sharika lahu; lahu-l-mulk wa lahu-l-hamd, wahuwa 'ala kulli
> shai'n qadir. Allahumma la mani'a Lima a taita, wa la mu'ta Lima
> mana'ta, wa la yanfa'u dhal-jaddu minkal-jadd.([Bukhari](http://www.sunnah.com/bukhari/80/27))

and

> ألا أعلمكم شيئًا تدركون به من سبقكم، وتسبقون به من بعدكم، ولا يكون أحد
> أفضل منكم إلا من صنع مثل ما صنعتم‏؟‏ قالوا‏:‏ بلى يا رسول الله، قال‏:‏
> ‏"‏تسبحون، وتحمدون، وتكبرون، خلف كل صلاة ثلاثًا وثلاثين قال أبو صالح
> الراوي عن أبي هريرة، لما سئل عن كيفية ذكرهن، قال‏:‏ يقول‏:‏ **سبحان
> الله، والحمد لله، والله أكبر**، حتى يكون منهن كلهن ثلاثًا وثلاثين‏.‏
> ‏(‏‏(‏متفق عليه‏)‏‏)‏‏
>
> Abu Hurairah (May Allah be pleased with him) reported: The poor
> Emigrants came to the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) and said: "The wealthy
> have gone with the highest ranks and lasting bliss." He asked: "How is
> that?" They replied: "They offer Salat (prayer) as we offer it; they
> observe fast as we do; (and as they are wealthy) they perform Hajj and
> 'Umrah, and go for Jihad, and they spend in charity but we cannot, and
> they free the slaves but we are unable to do so." The Messenger of
> Allah (ﷺ) said, "Shall I not teach you something with which you may
> overtake those who surpassed you and with which you will surpass those
> who will come after you? None will excel you unless he who does which
> you do." They said: "Yes, please do, O Messenger of Allah" He (ﷺ)
> said, "You should recite: Tasbih (Allah is free from imperfection),
> Takbir (Allah is Greatest), Tahmid (Praise be to Allah) thirty-three
> times after each Salat."
>
> [[Al-Bukhari and Muslim]](https://sunnah.com/riyadussalihin:1418).

and

> كَانَ يَقُولُ إِذَا صَلَّى الصُّبْحَ حِينَ يُسَلِّمُ ‏ "‏ **اللَّهُمَّ
> إِنِّي أَسْأَلُكَ عِلْمًا نَافِعًا وَرِزْقًا طَيِّبًا وَعَمَلاً
> مُتَقَبَّلاً ‏"‏ ‏.**
>
> It was narrated from Umm Salamah that when the Prophet (ﷺ) performed
> the Subh (morning prayer), while he said the Salam, he would say:
> ‘Allahumma inni as’aluka ‘ilman nafi’an, wa rizqan tayyiban, wa
> ‘amalan mutaqabbalan (O Allah, I ask You for beneficial knowledge,
> goodly provision and acceptable deeds).[[Ibn Majah]](http://www.sunnah.com/urn/1309770)’

And

> كان رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم إذا انصرف من صلاته ، **استغفر الله**
> ثلاثاً وقال‏:‏ ‏**"‏اللهم أنت السلام، ومنك السلام، تباركت يا ياذا الجلال**
> **والإكرام‏"‏** قيل للأوزاعي- وهو أحد رواته‏:‏ كيف الإستغفار‏؟‏ قال‏:‏
> يقول‏:‏ ‏"‏أستغفر الله ، أستغفر الله‏"‏
>
> Thauban (May Allah be pleased with him) reported: Whenever the
> Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) finished his Salat (prayer), he would beg
> forgiveness three times [by saying, 'Astaghfirullah' (3 times)] and
> then he would say: "Allahumma Antas-Salamu, wa minkas-Salamu,
> tabarakta ya Dhal-Jalali wal-Ikram. (O Allah! You are the Bestower of
> security and security comes from You; Blessed are You. O Possessor of
> glory and honour)." Imam Al-Auza'i (one of the subnarrators) of this
> Hadith was asked: "How forgiveness should be sought?" He replied: "I
> say: Astaghfirullah, Astaghfirullah (I seek forgiveness from Allah. I
> seek forgiveness from Allah)." [[Muslim]](https://sunnah.com/riyadussalihin:1876).

and

> فقال‏:‏ ‏"‏أوصيك يا معاذ لا تدعن في دبر كل صلاة تقول‏:‏ **اللهم أعني
> على ذكرك، وشكرك، وحسن عبادتك‏"‏**‏.‏ رواه أبو داود بإسناد صحيح‏.‏
>
> Mu'adh (May Allah be pleased with him) reported: The Messenger of
> Allah (ﷺ) took hold of my hand and said, "O Mu'adh! By Allah I love
> you, so I advise you to never forget to recite after every prayer:
> "Allahumma a'inni ala dhikrika, wa shukrika, wa husni 'ibadatika (O
> Allah, help me remember You, to be grateful to You, and to worship You
> in an excellent manner)." [[Abu Dawud]](https://sunnah.com/riyadussalihin:1422).

and

> عَنِ النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم أَنَّهُ كَانَ يُوتِرُ بِـ ‏{‏
> سَبِّحِ اسْمَ رَبِّكَ الأَعْلَى ‏}‏ وَ ‏{‏ قُلْ يَا أَيُّهَا
> الْكَافِرُونَ ‏}‏ وَ ‏{‏ قُلْ هُوَ اللَّهُ أَحَدٌ ‏}‏ وَيَقُولُ بَعْدَ
> مَا يُسَلِّمُ ‏"**‏ سُبْحَانَ الْمَلِكِ الْقُدُّوسِ** ‏"‏ ‏.‏ ثَلاَثَ
> مَرَّاتٍ يَرْفَعُ بِهَا صَوْتَهُ ‏
>
> It was narrated from Ibn Abdur-Rahman bin Abza from his father that:
> The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) used to recite in witr: "Glorify the Name
> of Your Lord, the Most High;' and "Say: O you disbelievers!'; and
> 'Say: He is Allah, (the) One." And after he had said the salam, he
> would say: Subhanal-Malikil-Quddus (Glory be to the Sovereign, the
> Most Holy) raising his voice the third time."([An Nasai](http://www.sunnah.com/nasai/20/153))

and

> عن عبد الله ابن الزبير رضي الله عنهما أنه كان يقول دبر كل صلاة، حين
> يسلم‏:‏ ل**ا إله إلا الله** **وحده لا شريك له ، له الملك وله الحمد ،
> وهو على كل شيء قدير ‏.‏ لا حول ولا** **قوة إلا بالله ،لا إله إلا الله،
> ولا نعبد إلا إياه، له النعمة، وله الفضل وله الثناء الحسن‏.‏ لا إله إلا
> الله مخلصين له الدين ولو كره الكافرون** It has been reported that
> 'Abdullah bin Zubair (May Allah be pleased with them) used to recite
> after Taslim at the conclusion of every Salat (prayer): "La ilaha
> illallahu wahdahu la sharika lahu, lahul- mulku, wa lahul-hamdu, wa
> Huwa 'ala kulli shai'in Qadir. La hawla wa la quwwata illa billah. La
> ilaha illallahu, wa la na'budu illa iyyahu, Lahun-ni'matu, wa
> lahul-fadlu, wa lahuth-thana'ul-hasan. La ilaha ilallahu, mukhlisina,
> lahud-dina, wa lau karihal-kafirun (there is no true god except Allah;
> He is One. To Him belongs the dominion and to Him is all praise, and
> He is Powerful over all things. There is no power and might except
> with (the help of) Allah. There is no God but Allah and we worship
> none except Him, to Him belongs the bounty and to Him belongs the
> grace, and to Him belongs all excellent praise; there is no deity but
> Allah. We reserve our devotion exclusively for Him though the
> disbelievers may detest it)." Ibn Az-Zubair said: The Messenger of
> Allah (ﷺ) used to celebrate Allah's Greatness in those terms after
> every Salat (prayer). ([Muslim](https://sunnah.com/riyadussalihin:1417))

and

> عن أبي أمامة ، قال: قال رسول الله: «من قرأ **آية الكرسي** في دبر كل صلاة
> مكتوبة، لم يمنعه من دخول الجنة إلا أن يموت
>
> Translation: Abi Amama (ra) narrates that the Prophet (Peace be upon
> him) said: Whosoever recites Ayat al Kursi after every Prayer then
> nothing can stop him from entering Paradise except for death (i.e. he
> will for sure enter paradise after death) [Sunnan Nasai,  At-Tabrani ,
> graded authentic by al albani.]

Allah Swt and His Messenger knows best.